# Deleting templated class pointers in a non-templated class destructor?

Tags: c++, templates

The below code `test-templated-destructor.cpp` replicates the organization of a library I'm using. I'm using:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
$ g++ -std=c++14
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++14’
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
$ g++ -std=c++11
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

There is:

- Base class `AA`, and classes derived from it `BB` and `CC`;
- Abstract class `AAInstancer`, and class derived from it `AAInstancerTemplated` which is templated
- class `AAHandler`, which has a templated function `addTemplatedObject`, which stores `AAInstancer*` pointers to `new AAInstancerTemplated<T>()` objects, in a `map` property of the class
- in `main()`, an `AAHandler` object is instantiated, and `.addTemplatedObject<BB>("BB");` called on it

If I run `valgrind` on this, it reports:

```
==21000== 43 (16 direct, 27 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==21000==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21000==    by 0x40141B: void AAHandler::addTemplatedObject<BB>(std::string) (test-templated-destructor.cpp:64)
==21000==    by 0x40113E: main (test-templated-destructor.cpp:82)
```

I think the problem is that we used `new` in `addTemplatedObject()`, thus we should correspondingly delete it latest at program exit - but that is not done, and thus the reason for the leak.

So I thought, to write an iterator that loops through the `instancers` map, and `delete`s these pointers in the desctructor of the `AAHandler`, but I can't:

- If I write:

```c++
  ~AAHandler() {
    cout << "  (running AAHandler destructor)" << endl;
    map<string, AAInstancer*>::iterator it;
    for ( it = instancers.begin(); it != instancers.end(); it++ ) {
      delete it->second;
    }
  }
```

... then I get at compilation:

```
$ g++ -g -Wall test-templated-destructor.cpp -o test-templated-destructor.exe
test-templated-destructor.cpp: In destructor ‘AAHandler::~AAHandler()’:
test-templated-destructor.cpp:60:18: warning: deleting object of abstract class type ‘AAInstancer’ which has non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behaviour [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
       delete it->second;
                  ^
```

... and it sounds right - `AAInstancer` doesn't have a destructor defined, so compiler probably auto-added is as non-virtual, leading to this warning (although, running this through `valgrind` will show that leaks are not detected anymore).

- If I write:

```c++
  template <class T>
  ~AAHandler() {
      cout << "  (running AAHandler destructor)" << endl;
      map<string, AAInstancer*>::iterator it;
      for ( it = instancers.begin(); it != instancers.end(); it++ ) {
        delete (AAInstancerTemplated<T>*)it->second;
      }
    }
```

... in hope that this destructor would get called if we called `addTemplatedObject` with some template (which it wouldn't anyway), compilation fails:

```
$ g++ -g -Wall test-templated-destructor.cpp -o test-templated-destructor.exe && ./test-templated-destructor.exe
test-templated-destructor.cpp:57:14: error: destructor ‘AAHandler::~AAHandler()’ declared as member template
   ~AAHandler() {
              ^
```

... and this makes sense too: `AAHandler` is a non-templated class, so probably its destructor shouldn't be templated either.

So, is it possible to write a destructor for `AAHandler`, which would `delete` all `new` pointers in its `instancers`, regardless of which template they were instantiated with - with minimal (or best, no) changes to the already existing code?

**`test-templated-destructor.cpp`**

```c++
// g++ -g -Wall test-templated-destructor.cpp -o test-templated-destructor.exe && ./test-templated-destructor.exe
// valgrind --leak-check=yes ./test-templated-destructor.exe

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class AA {
public:
  string myname;
  AA() {
    myname = "";
    cout << "  AA instantiated\n";
  }
};


class BB : public AA {
public:
  string mystuff;
  BB() {
    mystuff = "";
    cout << "  BB instantiated\n";
  }
};

class CC : public AA {
public:
  string mythings;
  CC() {
    mythings = "";
    cout << "  CC instantiated\n";
  }
};

class AAInstancer
{
public:
    virtual AA* createInstance() = 0;
    string tagName;
};

template <class T>
class AAInstancerTemplated: public AAInstancer
{
public:
    AA* createInstance() {
        return new T();
    }
};


class AAHandler
{
public:
    ~AAHandler() { }
    AAHandler() { }
    static map<string, AAInstancer*> instancers;

    template <class T>
    static void addTemplatedObject(string tagName) {
        AAInstancer* instancer = new AAInstancerTemplated<T>();
        instancer->tagName = tagName;
        instancers[tagName] = instancer;
    }

  AAHandler* get() {
    if(singleton == NULL)
      singleton = new AAHandler();
    return singleton;
  }
private:
    static AAHandler* singleton;
};
map<string, AAInstancer*> AAHandler::instancers;



int main()
{
  AAHandler aah;
  aah.addTemplatedObject<BB>("BB");

  cout << "Address of aah: " << static_cast<void*>(&aah) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not using `std::unique_ptr<AAInstancer>` instead of `AAInstancer*`?

Comment: How about `map<string, unique_ptr<AAInstancer>>` then you don't have to do anything?

Answer (score 1):

`AAInstancer` needs a virtual destructor.
If it doesn't need a body you can default it.

```
virtual ~AAInstancer() = default;
```

Comment: Thanks @John - I tried this: "`warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`";  compiling with `g++ -g -std=c++11 -Wall ...` passes, however, unfortunately the same leak is detected by `valgrind`

Comment: @sdaau Doesn't your compiiler support these suggested flags? Did you try doing that?

Comment: @user0042 - yes it does, just not by default - which is why I said "_compiling with `g++ -g -std=c++11 -Wall` ... passes_", - so the compilation is OK, but this change alone still leaks memory.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`std::unique_ptr<AAInstancer>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
map<string, std::unique_ptr<AAInstancer>>
```

as member, instead of managing the memory yourself.

Comment: Thanks @user0042, `std::unique_ptr` is also `-std=c++11` (else `error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’` even with `#include <memory>`); but when I replace the declaration and definition of `instancers` with `static map<string, std::unique_ptr<AAInstancer>>`, and change nothing else from OP, I get "`In instantiation of ‘static void AAHandler::addTemplatedObject ... -destructor.cpp:87:34:   required from here ... -destructor.cpp:68:23: error: no match for ‘operator=’ ....`" meaning now I have to do: ...

Comment: @sdaau https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714509/deleting-templated-class-pointers-in-a-non-templated-class-destructor/46714589#comment80375882_46714579

Comment: ... `addTemplatedObject` I have to use something like `std::unique_ptr<AAInstancer> instancer = std::unique_ptr<AAInstancer>(new AAInstancerTemplated<T>());`, which results with "`error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr...`"... Any suggestions?

Comment: @sdaau Which deleted function exactly? Maybe ask another question providing a [MCVE], then I could eventually help with this error.

Comment: the full line is: `error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = AAInstancer; _Dp = std::default_delete<AAInstancer>]’`, and the next `   instancers[tagName] = instancer;`

Comment: @sdaau The `operator=()` shouldn't be used for an initialization construction as you show in your comment.

Comment: Thanks @user0042 - if that means that I use `std::unique_ptr<AAInstancer> instancer = std::unique_ptr<AAInstancer>(AAInstancerTemplated<T>());`, then that fails with `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<AAInstancer>::unique_ptr(AAInstancerTemplated<BB>)’`

Comment: @sdaau No. Probably the best option is to use [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). `std::unique_ptr` doesn't support copy construction or assignment, but move construction and assignment only.

Comment: `std::make_unique` seems to be c++14, and unfortunately, my `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4)` compiler does not support `-std=c++14`.

Comment: @sdaau As mentioned, please ask another question with a [MCVE] and provide all that information ([tag:ubuntu], [tag:gcc], [tag:c++11]) . It's more likely you get your problem solved then.

Comment: -> "_As mentioned,_": where?; "_please ask another question with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_": how is the `test-templated-destructor.cpp` (and the compilation command inside) in my OP *not* a minimal, complete, and verifiable example?; "_and provide all that information (ubuntu, gcc, c++11)_": thanks, edited my post above.

Comment: @sdaau We need a question with your trial to use `std::unique_ptr` (don't do that in your current question please), and I mentioned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714509/deleting-templated-class-pointers-in-a-non-templated-class-destructor/46714589?noredirect=1#comment80376113_46714589) BTW.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally got something to work which compiles fine under just `c++11` and does not leak; `valgrind` reports:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./test-templated-destructor.exe==22888== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22888== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22888== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22888== Command: ./test-templated-destructor.exe
==22888== 
Address of aah: 0xffefffb3f
  (running AAHandler destructor)
  ~AAInstancerTemplated <2BB> here; tref: 0x5a200b0
    ~AAInstancer here
  ~AAInstancerTemplated <2CC> here; tref: 0x5a201e0
    ~AAInstancer here
==22888== 
==22888== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22888==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22888==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 198 bytes allocated
==22888== 
==22888== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22888== 
==22888== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22888== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Yup, no leaks - I like that `:)`

The approach is a bit classic: make `AAInstancerTemplated` keep a reference (here `tref`) to whatever it is instantiating via `new`, then create a destructor for it (for `AAInstancerTemplated`) that `delete`s this reference.

Note that even if in `AAHandler`, we store generic pointers `AAInstancer*` in `instancers`, while we instantiate templated objects (`new AAInstancerTemplated<T>();`) -- now, with this organisation, when we `delete it->second` which is of type `AAInstancer*`, the right templated destructor gets called.

The fixed `test-templated-destructor.cpp`:

```c++
// g++ -g -std=c++11 test-templated-destructor.cpp -o test-templated-destructor.exe && ./test-templated-destructor.exe
// valgrind --leak-check=yes ./test-templated-destructor.exe

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional> // note: uses std::function, which is c++11 feature

using namespace std;

class AA {
public:
  string myname;
  AA() {
    myname = "";
    cout << "  AA instantiated\n";
  }
};


class BB : public AA {
public:
  string mystuff;
  BB() {
    mystuff = "";
    cout << "  BB instantiated\n";
  }
};

class CC : public AA {
public:
  string mythings;
  CC() {
    mythings = "";
    cout << "  CC instantiated\n";
  }
};

class AAInstancer
{
public:
  virtual ~AAInstancer() {
    cout << "    ~AAInstancer here" << endl;
  }
  virtual AA* createInstance() = 0;
  string tagName;
};

template <class T>
class AAInstancerTemplated: public AAInstancer
{
public:
  T* tref;
  AA* createInstance() {
    if (tref) delete tref;
    tref = new T();
    return tref;
  }
  ~AAInstancerTemplated() {
    cout << "  ~AAInstancerTemplated <" << typeid(T).name() << "> here; tref: " << static_cast<void*>(&tref) << endl;
    if (tref) delete tref;
  }
};


class AAHandler
{
public:
  ~AAHandler() {
    cout << "  (running AAHandler destructor)" << endl;
    typedef typename map<string, AAInstancer*>::iterator instIterator;
    for ( instIterator it = instancers.begin(); it != instancers.end(); it++ ) {
      delete it->second;
    }
  }
  AAHandler() { }
  static map<string, AAInstancer*> instancers;

  template <class T>
  static void addTemplatedObject(string tagName) {
    AAInstancer* instancer = new AAInstancerTemplated<T>();
    instancer->tagName = tagName;
    instancers[tagName] = instancer;
  }

  AAHandler* get() {
    if(singleton == NULL)
      singleton = new AAHandler();
    return singleton;
  }
private:
  static AAHandler* singleton;
};
map<string, AAInstancer*> AAHandler::instancers;

int main()
{
  AAHandler aah;
  aah.addTemplatedObject<BB>("BB");
  aah.addTemplatedObject<CC>("CC");

  cout << "Address of aah: " << static_cast<void*>(&aah) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also note this works in this simple example, but might not work in more complex ones, where one cannot just `if (tref) delete tref;` in `createInstance`!